# Download mysql driver offline

Tags: mysql, linqpad

I have an offline LinqPad which I have succsesfully registered for autocompletion. How can I download the drivers for MySql for offline workstations?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the library here:

http://www.linqpad.net/RichClient/DataContextDrivers.aspx